# How to read a pdf in my application using other applications built in phone by 100 kB block

Tags: android, pdf

I am building an application in where I need to read an encrypted pdf . I will decrypt the pdf by 100kB  block . At first 100kB  will be decrypted . This block must be read by another pdf reader application built into phone .

After reading this 100 kB , another 100 kB data will be decrypted . This block will be read by the pdf reader application . The previous copy of 100 KB data will be encrypted . What can I do to achieve this goal ?

At present I have the following code in where there is no way to read a pdf by another application by 100 kb block .

```
Uri path_sultan = Uri.fromFile(file); 
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
        String ext =GetFileExtension(file.getAbsolutePath());

        if(ext.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")  )
            ext = "application/" +ext.toLowerCase() ;
        else if( ext.equalsIgnoreCase("epub") )
            ext = "application/" +ext.toLowerCase();
        intent.setDataAndType(path_sultan,ext); 

        try 
        { 
            startActivity(intent); 
        }  
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
        { 
           // Toast.makeText(this,"No Application Available to View PDF",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }       
    }
```

Guys can you help me in this regard ? I am badly needed your advice .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What can I do to achieve this goal ?

Write your own PDF renderer from scratch, most likely. PDF viewers need access to the entire stream, read in as they choose, not based on some arbitrary "100 kB" dividing line.

If you are willing to finesse the "100 kB" part, and simply decrypt the data on the fly as needed by the viewer, you can use a `ContentProvider` for that. Implement `openFile()`, using a `ParcelFileDescriptor` pipe, to allow the viewer to read from a stream that you write to, where you are writing the decrypted data.

[Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Pipe) demonstrating this technique, minus the actual decryption. [Here is another version of the same sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/GrantUriPermissions) that further limits access to only apps that I designate, by granting `Uri` permissions when I start up their activity.

Comment: thanks @Mark Murphy . I am learning android by reading your book . It is a great moment when I can directly communicate with my favorite author .

Comment: @OcenaPothik: I am humbled if you truly think of me as your favorite author. BTW, the second sample linked to above is not yet in the book, but should be in the next update, complete with an explanation of how it works.

Comment: I can not download from git-hub . What is the process ? Or can u mail it to "interested_to_programming@yahoo.com"

Comment: @OcenaPothik: Visit the repo home page (https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus) and click the ZIP button to download a ZIP archive of the entire repository.

Comment: I am able to run your code successfully but get exception in Pipe Content Provider . Can you check it ?